# Stored procedure outbound gateway is not returning any ResultSet for DB2 database

Tags: spring-integration

We are using DB2 database.I have configured the `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` in the following way:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
            auto-startup="true"
            data-source="routingDataSource" 
            stored-procedure-name="ZSPPQCIMGL"
            skip-undeclared-results="true"
            ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
            use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" 
            expect-single-result="true" >

                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_CLMN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ALTC1" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ALTC2" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ALTC3" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ALTC4" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_STRCRDATTIM" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                  <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_PAGESIZE" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />


                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_CLMN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//ClaimListResults/checkClaimSources/claimsCopy[1]/ClmNum')" />
                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ALTC1" expression="#xpath(payload, '//ClaimListResults/checkClaimSources/claimsCopy[1]/AltClaim')" />
                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ALTC2" expression="#xpath(payload, '//ClaimListResults/checkClaimSources/claimsCopy[1]/AltClaim')" />
                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ALTC3" expression="#xpath(payload, '//ClaimListResults/checkClaimSources/claimsCopy[1]/AltClaim')" />
                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ALTC4" expression="#xpath(payload, '//ClaimListResults/checkClaimSources/claimsCopy[1]/AltClaim')" />
                  <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_STRCRDATTIM" expression="#xpath(headers.originalRequest, '//lastCRDATTIM')" />
                              <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_PAGESIZE" expression="#xpath(headers.originalRequest, '//pageSize')" />

      <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper" row-mapper="com.dsths.cs.awd.utils.ResultSetRowMapper"/>

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

The above `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` is not returning any `ResultSet` which it supposed to return. I have written a standalone JDBC code using `callablestatement` and found that the `ResultSet` is returned after executing the stored procedure. But weirdly `stored-proc-outbound-gateway` is not returning the `ResultSet`. The stored procedure is below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ZSPPQCIMGL ( 
                                IN P_CLMN    CHAR(75),
                IN P_ALTC1   CHAR(75),
                IN P_ALTC2   CHAR(75),
                IN P_ALTC3   CHAR(75),
                IN P_ALTC4   CHAR(75),
                                IN P_STRCRDATTIM TIMESTAMP,
                                IN P_PAGESIZE  CHAR(10)
)


        RESULT SETS 1
    LANGUAGE SQL
    SET OPTION COMMIT=*CS, DFTRDBCOL=*NONE, DYNDFTCOL=*NO


P1 : BEGIN

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 

SELECT 

BE2.CRDATTIM AS CRDATETIME, CONCAT(CHAR(BE2.CRDATTIM), CONCAT(BE2.RECORDCD, BE2.CRNODE))  AS  AwdObjectID,  CONCAT(CHAR(W67.PCRDATTIM), CONCAT(W67.PRECORDCD, W67.PCRNODE))  AS AWDTransId, W0.UNITCD AS BusinesArea, W0.OBJTYPE AS SourceType, W0.OBJECTID AS PhisyscalFileRef, CRUSERID as CreatedUserID,BE.CLMN AS ClaimNumber, W03.UNITCD as TransBusinessArea,W03.WRKTYPE as TransWorkType,W03.STATCD as TransStatus,W03.QUEUECD as TransQueue

FROM BESCAN BE JOIN W67U999S W67 ON 
                                                      W67.PCRDATTIM = BE.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W67.PRECORDCD = BE.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W67.PCRNODE = BE.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                        JOIN W03U999S W03 ON 
                                                      BE.CRDATTIM = W03.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   BE.RECORDCD = W03.RECORDCD
                                                AND   BE.CRNODE = W03.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                                                JOIN  W00U999S W0 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = W67.CCRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = W67.CRECORDCD 
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = W67.CCRNODE
                                                JOIN  BESCAN BE2 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = BE2.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = BE2.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = BE2.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE2.RECORDCD = 'O'
                        WHERE (BE.CLMN  IN (P_CLMN,P_ALTC1,P_ALTC2,P_ALTC3,P_ALTC4 ))
                                                                                                AND BE2.CRDATTIM < P_STRCRDATTIM
UNION                       


SELECT BE2.CRDATTIM AS CRDATETIME, CONCAT(CHAR(BE2.CRDATTIM), CONCAT(BE2.RECORDCD, BE2.CRNODE))  AS  AwdObjectID,  CONCAT(CHAR(W67.PCRDATTIM), CONCAT(W67.PRECORDCD, W67.PCRNODE))  AS AWDTransId, W0.UNITCD AS BusinesArea, W0.OBJTYPE AS SourceType, W0.OBJECTID AS PhisyscalFileRef, CRUSERID as CreatedUserID 
,BE.CLMN AS ClaimNumber, W03.UNITCD as TransBusinessArea,W03.WRKTYPE as TransWorkType,W03.STATCD as TransStatus,W03.QUEUECD as TransQueue
FROM BEAG BE JOIN W67U999S W67 ON 
                                                      W67.PCRDATTIM = BE.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W67.PRECORDCD = BE.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W67.PCRNODE = BE.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                         JOIN W03U999S W03 ON 
                                                      BE.CRDATTIM = W03.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   BE.RECORDCD = W03.RECORDCD
                                                AND   BE.CRNODE = W03.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                                                JOIN  W00U999S W0 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = W67.CCRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = W67.CRECORDCD 
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = W67.CCRNODE
                                                JOIN  BEAG BE2 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = BE2.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = BE2.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = BE2.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE2.RECORDCD = 'O'
                        WHERE (BE.CLMN  IN (P_CLMN,P_ALTC1,P_ALTC2,P_ALTC3,P_ALTC4 ))
                                                                                                AND BE2.CRDATTIM < P_STRCRDATTIM
  UNION                      

SELECT BE2.CRDATTIM AS CRDATETIME, CONCAT(CHAR(BE2.CRDATTIM), CONCAT(BE2.RECORDCD, BE2.CRNODE))  AS  AwdObjectID,  CONCAT(CHAR(W67.PCRDATTIM), CONCAT(W67.PRECORDCD, W67.PCRNODE))  AS AWDTransId, W0.UNITCD AS BusinesArea, W0.OBJTYPE AS SourceType, W0.OBJECTID AS PhisyscalFileRef, CRUSERID as CreatedUserID 
 ,BE.CLMN AS ClaimNumber, W03.UNITCD as TransBusinessArea,W03.WRKTYPE as TransWorkType,W03.STATCD as TransStatus,W03.QUEUECD as TransQueue
FROM BECLAIM BE JOIN W67U999S W67 ON 
                                                      W67.PCRDATTIM = BE.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W67.PRECORDCD = BE.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W67.PCRNODE = BE.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                        JOIN W03U999S W03 ON 
                                                      BE.CRDATTIM = W03.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   BE.RECORDCD = W03.RECORDCD
                                                AND   BE.CRNODE = W03.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE.RECORDCD = 'T'
                                                JOIN  W00U999S W0 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = W67.CCRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = W67.CRECORDCD 
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = W67.CCRNODE
                                                JOIN  BECLAIM BE2 ON
                                                      W0.CRDATTIM = BE2.CRDATTIM
                                                AND   W0.RECORDCD = BE2.RECORDCD
                                                AND   W0.CRNODE = BE2.CRNODE
                                                AND       BE2.RECORDCD = 'O'
                        WHERE (BE.CLMN = P_CLMN OR BE.ALTC IN (P_ALTC1,P_ALTC2,P_ALTC3,P_ALTC4 ))
                                                                                                AND BE2.CRDATTIM < P_STRCRDATTIM

                                                ORDER BY AwdObjectID desc

                                                FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;


                OPEN C1 ;

END P1;
```

What could be issue here?

The `CallableStatement` code is below:

```
package com.test;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Types;



public class FolderRestructure {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:as400://XXX.40.103.XXX/ABC";
    private static final String DB_USER = "ABC";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "DEF";


    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try {

            callOracleStoredProcCURSORParameter();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private static void callOracleStoredProcCURSORParameter()
            throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String getDBUSERCursorSql = "{call ZSPPQCIMGL(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        // String getDBUSERCursorSql = "{call ZSPQALLIMGLKP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        //call ZSPPQCIMGL('12021000012A','CHAVA-00001','CHAVA-00001','CHAVA-00001','CHAVA-00001','2017-08-04-23.59.59.999999','4');
        try {

            Timestamp timestamp = null;

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
                java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("2017-08-08 23:59:59.999999");
                 timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
            } catch(ParseException e) { //this generic but you can control another types of exception
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            callableStatement = dbConnection.prepareCall(getDBUSERCursorSql);
            callableStatement.setString(1, "12021000012A");
            callableStatement.setString(2, "CHAVA-00001");
            callableStatement.setString(3, "CHAVA-00001");
            callableStatement.setString(4, "CHAVA-00001");
            callableStatement.setString(5, "CHAVA-00001");
            callableStatement.setTimestamp(6, timestamp);
            callableStatement.setString(7, "4");
            //callableStatement.registerOutParameter(8, DB2Types.CURSOR);
                //P_CLMN=12021000012A, P_STRCRDATTIM=9999-99-99 99:99:99.999999, P_PAGESIZE=4, P_ALTC3=CHAVA-00001, P_ALTC4=CHAVA-00001, P_ALTC1=CHAVA-00001, P_ALTC2=CHAVA-00001
           /* callableStatement.setString(1, "DT207030");
            callableStatement.setString(2, "KKMTEST2000");
            callableStatement.setString(3, "");
            callableStatement.setString(4, "2XSRCTYP");
            callableStatement.setString(5, "0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000");
            callableStatement.setString(6, "9999-99-99 99:99:99.999999");
            callableStatement.setString(7, "9999-99-99 99:99:99.999999");*/



            // execute getDBUSERCursor store procedure
            rs = callableStatement.executeQuery();

            // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
            //rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(7);

            while (rs.next()) {
                //  CASEID , CASEBA, CASEWK,  CASESTA,  CASEQUE, ISSUEID , ISSUEBA,  ISSUEWK,  ISSUESTA,  ISSUEQUE,  ISSUEASIGNID,
                //         OBJECTID ,  OBJECTBA, OBJECTWK, OBJECTPHYFILEID,  OBJECTCREATEDUSERID

                //W0.OBJTYPE AS SourceType, W0.OBJECTID AS PhisyscalFileRef, CRUSERID as CreatedUserID,BE.CLMN AS ClaimNumber, 
                //W03.UNITCD as TransBusinessArea,W03.WRKTYPE as TransWorkType,W03.STATCD as TransStatus,W03.QUEUECD as TransQueue
                System.out.println("CRDATIM : " + rs.getString("CRDATETIME"));
                System.out.print("  AwdObjectID : " + rs.getString("AwdObjectID"));
                System.out.print("  AWDTransId : " + rs.getString("AWDTransId"));
                System.out.print("  BusinesArea : " + rs.getString("BusinesArea"));
                System.out.print("  SourceType : " + rs.getString("SourceType"));
                System.out.print("  PhisyscalFileRef : " + rs.getString("PhisyscalFileRef"));
                System.out.print("  CreatedUserID : " + rs.getString("CreatedUserID"));
                System.out.print("  ClaimNumber : " + rs.getString("ClaimNumber"));
                System.out.print("  TransBusinessArea : " + rs.getString("TransBusinessArea"));
                System.out.print("  TransWorkType : " + rs.getString("TransWorkType"));
                System.out.print("  TransStatus : " + rs.getString("TransStatus"));
                System.out.print("  TransQueue : " + rs.getString("TransQueue"));

             /*   String userid = rs.getString("ISSUEID");
                String userName = rs.getString("ISSUEBA");
                String createdBy = rs.getString("ISSUEWK");
                String createdDate = rs.getString("ISSUESTA");

                System.out.print("  ISSUEID : " + userid);
                System.out.print("  ISSUEBA : " + userName);
                System.out.print("  ISSUEWK : " + createdBy);
                System.out.print("  ISSUESTA : " + createdDate);*/
                // System.out.println("created : " + rs.getString("CASEQUE"));

               /* System.out.println("AwdObjectID : " + userid);
                System.out.println("BusinesArea : " + userName);
                System.out.println("SourceType : " + createdBy);
                System.out.println("PhisyscalFileRef : " + createdDate);
                System.out.println("created : " + rs.getString("CASEQUE"));*/
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }

            if (callableStatement != null) {
                callableStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }

    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {

            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        try {

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return dbConnection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        return dbConnection;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you definitely return the CURSOR from your procedure. So, it is `function` though.

Try this: `is-function="true"`

```
 <xsd:attribute name="is-function" default="false">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            If "true", a SQL Function is called. In that case
            the "stored-procedure-name" attribute defines
            the name of the called function.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:simpleType>
        <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:boolean xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:attribute>
```

Comment: I am getting the error `[SQL0440] Routine ZSPPQCIMGL in *N not found with specified parameters.` after adding `is-function="true"`.

Comment: Ok. Show, please, then working `callablestatement` to compare.

Comment: You mean any screen print of working `callablestatement `?

Comment: Added the code to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: How about to declare the 6th `P_STRCRDATTIM` in the Gateway as a `TIMESTAMP` as well? Looking to your `CallableStatement` sample I'd say it is exactly `is-function="true" any way. Your problem with incompatible parameter definition

Comment: Nope, same error despite of changing it to `TIMESTAMP `.

Comment: How does it work with `TIMESTAMP` (that's only the way to meet proc spec), without `is-function`, but with the `return-value-required="true"`?\

Comment: BTW, you always can switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.jdbc` category and follow logs what's going on with the proc execution. Also that would be great to see the whole StackTrace